# SharePoint provider hosted app - IRemoteEventService - Redirect call

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

We have a provider hosted app deployed in Azure that handles list item events for item create/update etc. It handles traffic from lot of different sites. We want to split the traffic among different services for load balancing and reliability.

We want to keep single URL for remote event service so that all events are registered for this single URL. Once we get the event, we want to route to secondary services based on SP site URL/List name etc. which are available in the parameter SPRemoteEventProperties.

```
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties);
```

What is the recommended way to route the call from main service to secondary services for this scenario based on values in properties param. We want the entire context of the call being passed to secondary service. We can write code in ProcessOneWayEvent to read properties param and then call the other service but looking for any better way as this may not pass the calling user context to secondary service.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about performance and reliability under scale, consider using your RER as a broker and dump the incoming request onto a service bus or Azure queue, and process the data from there. (This will only work if your RER's are asynchronous.)

I expect the user context would propagate just fine, but you could test that out easily enough.

You would have to have an awful lot of traffic to need to be worried about overloading an Azure web app. I have an RER in production on an S1 instance that handles 100k requests per day without a hitch. If you're offloading your processing to a back end service, your overhead on the app service will be very light.

Comment: We are doing ~70K per day. Some events take 30+ seconds to process as we do archival of SP list item and all related items/attachments etc. to another site. We are doing OK, but sometimes response time shoots up. Bulk of events are async so we will look into going for queuing solution. Thanks!
I am also looking into IDispatchMessageInspector :: AfterReceiveRequest to re-route as a quick fix.